Handling write permission to sqlite db file on deploy an ASP.NET Core Web API
I developed an ASP.NET Core Web API that has a sqlite db, so when deploying to IIS, it needs to give write access to iis_usrs that app can write to the database.
Is there any way that we did not need give write permission to the database file on each deploy, because the app will be deployed on different servers.

Normally, after you host your application inside the IIS, it will use the IIS application pool identity's permission to access the database not the iis_usrs.
If you are using the asp.net core web api and use the API's package like EF core or sqlconnection, there is no need to modify the iis_usrs, since it use the application pool identity permission not the IIS_Users to modify the sqllite database.
You should modify the sqllite folder's security folder to make sure the application pool identity contains the write permission.
Also the application pool identity contains the same permission as the iis_iuser.
Besides, since this is the server settings, I don't suggest you manage it during the deployment. You could write a scripts at the folder and after deployment you could ask the server administrator to run it to avoid security issue .
